# How is it possible to adjust the page's cache settings?

Tags: caching, web-storage

I would like my website to update at midnight (get the new data from the MariaDB database and refresh images, etc.) after that I want to cache (save) it throughout the day so that it doesn't have to use (PHP) and the database every time. Is that possible? It is important that the information can be freshly loaded at exactly midnight (or from zero when the first request is made) and is then constant for the entire website and every user until the next midnight. And in which file do you have to edit this in php.ini?

Comment: That's not a php setting

Comment: You mean "cache", not "catch".

Comment: Ok I See, my Bad

Comment: You could use a static HTML page, which you update every night with a cron job.